# Switch Target Framework in VS.NET 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, target-framework

Is there a way to change the target framework of all the projects of a solution in one fell swoop?  Changing the target on 18 projects is a little tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a search on the project files for

`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`

and replace with the desired version.

Answer (score 5):

Scott Dorman wrote a macro to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74805/Visual-Studio-2010-and-Target-Framework-Version.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you change the Target Framework in VS2010.

1. Right click the **Project**.
2. Click the "**Compile**" tab
3. At the bottom click "**Advanced Complie Options...**"
4. Choose the framework from "**Target framework (all configurations):**"

Answer (score 0):

Can you record a macro and then loop it through all projects in the solution? (Haven't used 2k10 yet.)